# recipe with Makefile in subdirectory

Tags: makefile, recipe

I'm writing a yocto recipe that uses a Makefile style package, not autotools.
I fetch the code from git correctly but the Makefile is not in the root folder, it's in a subfolder. I've tried the option:

> EXTRA_OEMAKE += "-I${S}/include -C${MAKEFILE_FOLDER}"

but make doesn't find the target. Can anyone give me a hand on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.  You should say what and where the file is that you are writing the above text in, and isolate that file to the smallest possible case that reproduces the problem.  You should quote what command you are using, from what directory, and what the error message is.

Through the process of isolation you will often come up with the solution yourself.

In any case, it seems you are confusing compiler options and Make options.

`-C $(DIR)` is an option for the `make` program
`-I $(DIR)` is an option for the compiler

You cannot generally give options to two different programs at once and hope that the first program will pass the second option to the second program.